# Python script on refreshing a web page, count value varies

Tags: python

I'm new to developing python scripts, but i'm trying to develop a script that will inform me when web page has been updated. For each check I use a counter to see how many times the program has run until the site has updated in someway.

My doubt is that, when I feed the url "stackoverflow.com", my program can run upto 6 times, however when I feed the url "stackoverflow.com/questions" the program runs at most once. Both sites on refreshing seems to be updating their questions often. But could someone explain to me why is there a big difference on the number of times the program runs?

```
  import urllib2
import time
refreshcnt=0
url=raw_input("Enter the site to check");
x=raw_input("Enter the time duration to refresh");
x=int(x);
url="http://"+url
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
htmlnew=html
while html==htmlnew:
    time.sleep(x)
    try:
        htmlnew=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except IOError:
        print "Can't open site"
        break
    refreshcnt+=1
    print "Refresh Count",refreshcnt
print("The site has updated!");
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how much SO updates and not about a programming problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ is (by default) set to the "Interesting" tab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions is (again, by default) set to the "Newest" tab. I'd imagine that the "Interesting" tab updates a lot less often than the "Newest" tab meaning that the HTML will change at different rates.

Comment: That's unusual, I'd expect the loop to break almost immediately for _both_ pages. All posts have a "asked X minutes ago" label, so when a minute elapses, shouldn't the X change and terminate your script?

Comment: @Kevin I wonder if the "asked X minutes ago" is from AJAX/JS/some_crazy_web_thing_that_doesn't_necessarily_affect_html?

Comment: @Kevin I noticed that too, which made me confused. It's also on sites like Facebook.com. Even when i'm not logged in, the program runs at most once. But I dont see any visible change on the login page every time I reload. I'm just curious on the concept of what's actually happening

Comment: It could be something innocuous, like the ads changing every page load. It may be a better idea to only look at a specific subset of the page data. For example, for StackOverflow, extract a list of question titles, and ignore everything else.

Comment: So if I used a plain site, with simply text and no ads, it probably run an infinite amount times correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this little loop to the end of your code and see what's changing:

```
for i in xrange(min(len(htmlnew),len(html))):
    if htmlnew[i] != html[i]:
        print(htmlnew[i-20:i+20])
        print(html[i-20:i+20])
        break
```

I tried it quick and it appears that there is a `ServerTime` key that is updated every second. For one reason or another, it would appear that this key is updated every second on the "/questions" page, but is only updated every half a minute or so on the homepage.

However, doing a couple other quick checks, this is certainly not the only part of the HTML being updated on the "stackoverflow.com/questions" page. Just comparing the entire HTML against the old one probably won't work in many situations. You'll likely want to search for a specific part of the HTML and then see if that piece has changed. For example, look for the HTML signifying the title newest question on SO and see if that title is different than before.